# Relating arcs and paths in topology

Tags: general-topology

There seems to be slightly varying definitions in the literature for {\bf arc} and {\bf path}. So, here I am using the following: If $S$ is a space and $I$ denotes the closed unit interval, and if $f:I\to S$, then define: (A) if $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is called a {\bf path}, and (B) if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f(I)$ is called an {\bf arc}. I have two questions. From the literature, it seems that two statements must be true: (1) If $S$ is a metric space, then $S$ is Hausdorff. (2) If $S$ is a Hausdorff space, $X\subset S$ contains at least two points, and $f:I\to X$ is onto, then $f$ is a path if and only if $f(I)$ is an arc ($f$ itself is not the homeomorphism, but some onto function $g:I\to f(I)$ is).

Question 1: Are statements (1) and (2) true? If not, what is wrong?

Question 2: If all above is correct, then is the following true? Suppose $S$ is a metric space, $f:I\to S$ is a path, and $J=[a,b],a<b$ is a closed sub-interval of $I$. Then $f(J)$ is an arc.

Comment: I know that $(1)$ is true, since you have metric space, given $x,y\in S$ you can always set $B_{\varepsilon/2}(x)$ and $B_{\varepsilon/2}(y)$ which are two open thaht contains $x$ and $y$ and that are disjoint

Comment: Your second statement needs refinement. The image of a path need not be an arc. But if there is a path there is also an arc.

Comment: bf does not woek outside math mode on this site; instead us ``**bold**`` codes and `*italic*` in markdown style in text mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a metric space is Hausdorff.

And (2) is also true in this improved variant (but rather hard to show, we need theory about Peano continua and characterisations of $[0,1]$, all early 20-th century stuff, but not very generally taught anymore): If $x \neq y$ in a Hausdorff space and there exists a path $f:I \to X$ from $x$ to $y$ then we can also find an arc from $x$ to $y$. In shorter terms, a path-connected Hausdorff space is arcwise-connected as well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working through Nadler's book on continuum theory, and my query came to light while thinking about the $\sin(1/x)$ continuum (i.e., the closure). Fun stuff I spent a lot of graduate school effort with back in the 70s. Today, just a hobby before my brain rots.